# How to push a MFMailComposeViewController? (iOS 5)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiactionsheet, mfmailcomposer

From a tableview I want to present a MFMailComposeViewController. I don't want to use the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method, but instead *push* the view controller, so it's consistent with the other animations from this table view.

Because MFMailComposeViewController is a UINavigationController and pushing a navigation controller is not supported, I used:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:[mailComposer topViewController] animated:YES];
```

This works, but when I tap the Cancel button it gives the warning:

> Presenting action sheet clipped by its superview. Some controls might not respond to touches. On iPhone try -[UIActionSheet showFromTabBar:] or -[UIActionSheet showFromToolbar:] instead of -[UIActionSheet showInView:].

The Cancel button at the bottom of the UIActionSheet doesn't respond to touches. Does anyone know whether it is possible to push a MFMailComposeViewController?

Comment: You already answer your question - _MFMailComposeViewController is a UINavigationController and pushing a navigation controller is not supported_

Comment: But you can push MFMailComposeViewController's UIViewController. Or is this not supported?

Comment: You code pushes UIViewController (topViewController returns it). It's a normal behavior.

Comment: Yes I know, but downside is the UIActionSheet warning when you use the MailComposer's cancel button. So it doesn't seem supported or I'm missing a step (like telling this view controller to use [self navigationController] as it's navigationController).

Comment: I think this UIActionSheet called from navigation which contains MailComposer and this action sheet cann't find (or do) something because you have only part of navigation hierarchy (missing navigationBar or toolBar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presenting a `MFMailComposeViewController` as a modal view is consistent with Apple's HIG. Pushing it onto a navigation stack is not. Use `-presentModalViewController:animated:` (or `-presentViewController:animated:completion:` if executing on iOS 5 or greater)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. OK, so there's no way animate a MailComposer right to left? It seems a bit weird that this animation is not supported. I don't think it's clear for the user why the "Send email" function animates from the top and all the other functions from this tableview are animated with a right to left push.

Comment: You can use `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal` as well. Otherwise, the right to left transition is intended for indicating the user is drilling down into the information hierarchy. Presenting the mail composer is intended to be a "break in the action" and is intended to be a modal action. Grabbing the view controller hierarchy from a self contained `UINavigationController` component is a receipt for a broken application down the road should Apple change its behavior or structure.

Comment: For future knowledge, `presentModalViewController:animated:` has been deprecated by Apple, so you should use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead.